# Angular2 RC1, how to use ngc to compile static offline

Tags: angular, systemjs

Trying to build client-side app by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSssb9AmiJU&feature=youtu.be&t=25m25s

All is clear, except where `ngc` command comes from? it's not part of the `package.json` scripts that's shown in the video and it's not being added once you install `@angular/platform-server` package. As it's said in the video, `ngc` is the internal compiler of Angular2 which will pre-compile all typescript that's built by SystemJS-Builder afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that has yet to be shipped. It's working in internal experimental builds they use for ng-conf but it's IMHO not yet working in RC.1

See https://docs.google.com/document/d/150lerb1LmNLuau_a_EznPV1I1UHMTbEl61t4hZ7ZpS0/edit# from "May 23"

Comment: So is there another way of building RC1 bundle? Apparently concat and uglify on `*.umd.js` in @angular don't do the job. I even tried to bundle everything `*.js` and still no luck. So how to bundle it?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I don't know TS (only Dart myself).

Comment: It's alright, but i don't think this is TS dependent. How do you do your RC1 bundle?

Comment: RC is not yet available for Dart :-/ Dart has its own build tools which are entirely different than those of TS.

Answer (score 0):

This post is extremely useful for for learning how to bundle all your angular 2 code into a single bundle, it uses browserify and uglifyjs to achieve the fit and the result is somewhat decent. you can also perform tree shaking which is the process of removing exports that are unused.

[Building Angular 2 for Production](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/)

It features an example using ngc however it seems that the tool has yet to see the light of day.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are good as well, but this original documentation must be seen also.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html